# Using Metal for 64-bit Number Crunching

Tags: ios8, accelerate-framework, metal

There is an [article](http://memkite.com/blog/2014/12/18/gpgpu-performance-of-swiftmetal-vs-accelerate-on-iphone-6-5s-ipad-air-and-ipad-mini/) claiming that Metal could be faster than the Accelerate framework for computing with large arrays of numbers.

After looking at the documentation of Metal's shader language, I realized that there is no support for arrays of double-precision floats or 64-bit integers. Am I overlooking something? I thought Metal was designed for the 64-bit A7 processor?

Comment: I take it that arrays of double-precision floats or 64-bit integers are necessary for 64-bit A7 use?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I was just puzzled that, having a processor with the capability of performing 64-bit arithmetic, the shader language does not support it. I was just wondering if I had overlooked something. Sorry if it sounded like a rant; it was not meant to be one.

Comment: 64 bit doesn't always mean 64-bit end-to-end.  Processors can be 64 bit internally, but still use smaller numbers in and out; it happens all the time.  I know absolutely nothing about shaders, but it seems to me that your final numbers need be no higher in resolution than, say, your highest possible pixel count times the color count, which probably numbers in the billions, not the quadrillions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPU on A7 supports 64-bit integers and double-precision float.  The GPU does not.  Metal shaders run on the GPU, not the CPU.

As an aside, the benchmark in that blog post is extremely questionable.  It's using Accelerate in spectacularly inefficient fashion.  While it's certainly possible for well written Metal to be faster than correct usage of the Accelerate interfaces, that's not what the benchmark is really showing.

Comment: How would a more efficient Accelerate approach be written? I would be happy to run new benchmarks. (I wrote the blog post mentioned)

Comment: One thing about the blog post that I noticed is that the pure Swift implementation uses overflow checked operators. Metal and accelerate don't do overflow checking and using checked operators in Swift prevents autovectorization. Use unchecked operators instead (`&+`, `&*`, ...). Also use `UnsafeMutablePointer`, because it doesn't perform bounds checking. Also, don't use vectors of ones or negative ones in the Accelerate code. Use `vDSP_` scalar-vector functions.